# How do I set the default font on Telerik's RadEditor?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

There must be an easy way to set the default selected font of the Font Name dropdown list.
I've been looking around on the Telerik site and forums but I can't find a simple way.  Maybe there is no simple way, but maybe I just can't find it.

Here is my RadEditor:

```
      <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" ContentFilters="MakeUrlsAbsolute,ConvertToXhtml,RemoveScripts"
                    EditModes="All" EnableResize="false" Font-Bold="false" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt"
                    Height="230px" MaxHtmlLength="3000" MaxTextLength="3000" NewLineMode="Br" Skin="Web20">
                    <Tools>
                        <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                            <telerik:EditorTool Name="ImageManager" />
                            <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="FontName" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="FontSize" />
                            <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="BackColor" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="ForeColor" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Bold" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Italic" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Underline" />
                            <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Copy" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Cut" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="Paste" />
                            <telerik:EditorTool Enabled="true" Name="AjaxSpellCheck" Text="Spell Check" />
                        </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    </Tools>
                    <ImageManager MaxUploadFileSize="1048576" SearchPatterns="*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp, *.ico"
                        UploadPaths="~/images/" ViewPaths="~/images/" />
                </telerik:RadEditor>
```

I hope one of you out there can tell me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

The editor:

```
 <telerik:RadEditor ID="myEditor" OnClientLoad="RadEditorLoad" runat="server" ... >
```

Handler:

```
        function RadEditorLoad(editor, eventArgs) {

            // Set the Editor Default Font to Arial

             editor.get_contentArea().style.fontFamily = 'Arial'
        }
```

Found this at: 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/radeditor-setting-font.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This article might be helpful http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-default-font-for-editable-content.html

You can also set the default FontName header dropdown value in the OnClientLoad event using this code:

```
var tool = editor.getToolByName("FontName");
tool.set_value("Tahoma");
```

Comment: The OnClientLoad way works!  Thank you!!!

I used this for the OnLoad:
function RadEditorLoad(sender, eventArgs) {

                var tool = sender.getToolByName("FontName");
                tool.set_value("Arial");

            }

Comment: Well it does change the selection to Arial, but then when I click inside the text area, it changes it to "Times New Roman", maybe there is a Js event for when I click inside there area that I need to handle

Answer (score 0):

Create a css file 'RadEditorContentArea.css' with the following content:

```
body 
{  
   font-family: Arial!important;
}
```

Add this css file as the editor css file as follows

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1">
    <CssFiles>
        <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/RadEditorContentArea.css" />
    </CssFiles>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Check out this link for  more: 
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/content-area-appearance/default-font-for-editable-content